Force Same Region Azure Storage Account Requests to use Internet
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-powershell#restrictions-for-ip-network-rules

Services deployed in the same region as the storage account use private Azure IP addresses for communication. So, you can't restrict access to specific Azure services based on their public outbound IP address range.

Is there any way around this? My specific use case is I have some AVD machines behind an Azure Firewall that is supposed to be blocking all traffic except for a small set of allowlisted sites. It seems that requests to storage accounts in the same region are completely bypassing my firewall.

There’s no way to force connections from the same region to use the internet. But IPv6 connectivity to storage endpoints is expected to address this limitation of SNAT bypass
